# How to continuous assign a variable to a dataframe row (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
BK = pd.DataFrame([], columns=(['Datetime','X','Y','Z']))  

Time = 08082012
A1 = 28.455
B1 = 14.675
C1 = 124.674

# Assign first four values under 'Datetime','X','Y','Z'
# Assign next values in a row under the first values

Time = 09082012
A1 = 28.923
B1 = 14.122
C1 = 123.158

# Assign next values in a row under the second values
Time = 10082012
A1 = 27.923
B1 = 15.122
C1 = 127.158
```

Let's assume that the number of rows can be infinite.
How would one assign the variables into a dataframe row after row?
Can there be anomalies if I keep overwriting the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BK = pd.DataFrame([], columns=(['Datetime','X','Y','Z']))  
rows = [[Time],[A1],[B1],[C1]]
BK.loc[len(BK)] = rows
```

=

```
BK.loc[len(BK)]= [[Time],[A1],[B1],[C1]]
```

Easy and quick, especially if one would use a loop of some sorts.

Comment: Are you sure? In my opinion if creates list and then dataframe constructor is is more quicker. Can you add some timings for it?

Comment: Hi jazrael, you only have to create the dataframe once it the beginning or so and afterwards it adds the variables to the row. As I am writing this comment, there might be also the possibility that one could direct the data directly to the dataframe. I have to figure that out.

Comment: I only think the best solution is create list and then dataframe, because it is fast, easy and recomended (as say Dov Grobgeld in his answer). So I am surprised you think create row to row data to dataframe is quick - in my opinion not. Or something missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is create nested list (or list of tuples) and then assign to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
#one possible solution for create nested list, try modify for real data
L = [x for x in function_generate_rows()] 

#another possible solution
L = []
for x in range(5):
    row = function_generate_rows(x)
    L.append(row)

print (L)
[[08082012,28.455,14.675,124.674],[09082012,28.923,14.122,123.158], ...]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns = ['Datetime','X','Y','Z'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following also works, but it is probably slower than first creating a list and at the end turning it into a dataframe (which is what I usually do):

```
import pandas as pd

BK = pd.DataFrame([], columns=(['Datetime','X','Y','Z']))  

Time = 8082012
A1 = 28.455
B1 = 14.675
C1 = 124.674

BK=BK.append({'Datetime':Time,'X':A1,'Y':B1,'Z':C1}, ignore_index=True)
# Assign first four values under 'Datetime','X','Y','Z'
# Assign next values in a row under the first values

Time = 9082012
A1 = 28.923
B1 = 14.122
C1 = 123.158
BK=BK.append({'Datetime':Time,'X':A1,'Y':B1,'Z':C1}, ignore_index=True)

# Assign next values in a row under the second values
Time = 10082012
A1 = 27.923
B1 = 15.122
C1 = 127.158
BK=BK.append({'Datetime':Time,'X':A1,'Y':B1,'Z':C1}, ignore_index=True)

print BK
```